# Do I have a chance at an MSc in Machine Learning/AI with low grades?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science, united-kingdom

I am currently applying to a Master's programme at a strong university in the UK and began doubting my chances of getting in.

I completed my Bachelor's degree in Mathematics at a large research university in the UK a few years ago but my grades were below the 2:1 UK grade minimum for this course by a few percent. I have since worked at a large company doing data science and research and really enjoyed the work. I have been doing well here, getting some strong programming skills as well in Python and R. I also published an application paper on machine learning at a conference and presented at some others as well and have experience working on research projects.

However, I am worried that my chances are low because my grades have not been the greatest and that they will overlook my work experience. Do I still have a chance?

Comment: related https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly

Comment: Check out the research papers in a direction that interests you. Is that something you can cope with? Do you have a direction that you want to pursue? Marks are important, but you might get away with less (unless there is a formal limit in place) if you show competence, motivation, and a good understanding of the research landscape.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply: Your chance is equal to **zero** if you do not apply. But greater than zero, if you give it a shot. The worst they can do is not accept you. Which leaves you in the same state as when you would not apply at all.